# Why has a class to be std::is_trivially_copyable and not std::is_trivially_copy_constructible to be useable with memcpy

Tags: c++

According to various sources (for example [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)), a class has to be trivially copyable to be useable with memcpy, but I don't understand why a trivially copy constructible class isn't enough.
The extra properties of trivially copyable classes (like a trivial destructor) shouldn't matter, as long as I make sure the destructor gets called a the appropriate time.

Could anybody provide an example or an explanation, when using memcpy on a class with for example a non-trivial destructor (or move constructor) would lead to problems?

Comment: If you already have an existing object then altering its value with `memcpy` is not construction, it's closer to assignment. So thinking that only the copy constructor matters is wrong.

Comment: @jonathan-wakely I don't have an existing object, I only have some memory. Conceptually, it's similiar to placement new.

Comment: So are you suggesting the language rules should be tailored for your specific use case that you have right now? The rules cover copying an existing object to uninitialized memory, but they also cover copying an existing object to another existing object. Just because you only care about the first case right now doesn't mean the rules are wrong.

Comment: And if you want to initialize raw memory, what's wrong with placement new anyway? Why would `memcpy` be preferable?

Comment: @jonathan-wakely I'm kinda wondering what is_trivially_copy_constructible is actually useful for, if not for my use case. And if/where my usecase will run into trouble.

Comment: @jonathan-wakely I can use memcpy without having to have access to the actual type at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

> The extra properties of trivially copyable classes (like a trivial destructor) shouldn't matter, as long as I make sure the destructor gets called a the appropriate time.

That's a big "if", though, isn't it? These rules are intended to protect you from invoking UB which would be extremely easy if it were legal to bit-wise copy an object that needed non-trivial destruction. And then ... what does that non-trivial destructor do? `delete` resources that are now shared? That's just begging for problems with the rule of three.

If you want to copy a complex object that manages resources, you *really* should be copying it properly, using the copy constructor. `std::memcpy` is provided for backward compatibility, and should only be used with objects that don't have other objects to manage. Because madness that way lies.

Comment: It's not any more dangerous then for example aligned_storage. And a password class (with an embedded password) could for example call memset in it's destructor to prevent the plain text password from staying in memory for unbound amounts of time.

Comment: @SananeLan: Yes, it _could_. But as a language specification author, why go out of your way to allow more dangerous things than you actually need to? As the OP, why do you need to `std::memcpy` a non-trivial type? Y'know, you might as well post a new SO question asking why we need constructors and destructors at all, since you _can_ just clean everything up manually, right?